# Page Speed Insights API Missing Property: Cannot read property 'FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS' of undefined

Tags: javascript

When I query the Google Page Speed API data is missing in the response.

Response when querying url https://www.online-it-support.dk using Pagespeed API https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.online-it-support.dk

The loadingExperience property is almost empty.

```
{
    "captchaResult": "CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED",
    "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
    "id": "https://marketing-manager.dk/",
    "loadingExperience": {
        "initial_url": "https://marketing-manager.dk/"
    },
    "lighthouseResult": {
```

When querying developers.google.com (https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://developers.google.com/)

the loadingExperince is filled with data

```
{
    "captchaResult": "CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED",
    "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
    "id": "https://developers.google.com/",
    "loadingExperience": {
        "id": "https://developers.google.com/",
        "metrics": {
            "CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT_SCORE": {
                "percentile": 31,
                "distributions": [
                    {
                        "min": 0,
                        "max": 10,
                        "proportion": 0.28354700854700876
                    },
```

Any idea what this is caused by?
I have  tried with an API key but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out that it is caused by to little data on the website. In Google Page Speed it also says it lacks data so only data in lighthouseResult is present.